# find out the position of a div while browser scrollbar moves using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div and I need to find its position when the browser scrollbar is moved up or down. This would help me detect the current position of this div and depending on the current position of this div I can place another div on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the position like this:

```
var offset = $('#element').offset();
alert(offset.top + offset.left);
```